# Doubts regarding Django views

Tags: django, mongodb

I am building a website using django and mongodb. I am having some doubts regarding django views. I am new in django and I till now understood that views can be mapped with urls in django. But I am confused that if I have a mongodb document like this:

```
{
  "articles":{
       "Mercedes":"path of this article",
       "BMW":"path of this article",
       "Jeep":"path of this article",
   }
}
```

and I want the user should see the article name in the address bar like:

```
mydomain.com/mercedes...
```

But in django, we map the views in urls.py, so do I need to write a function(view) for each article and need to map in urls.py like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from my1app import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('articles/mercedes',views.viewMercedesArticle, name='viewMercedesArticle')
]
```

or this can have a single view which can show multiple articles and *urls of article name* in address bar of user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django uses regex for url matching, you can use urls like

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('articles/(?P<article>\w+)/',views.viewMercedesArticle, 
         name='viewMercedesArticle')
]
```

and in your views you can take article name as

```
def viewMercedesArticle(request, article):
    pass # here article is dynamic
```

you can refer this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls) for more details.